# How to turn a MongoDB query into a dictionary

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have a collection in my MongoDB:

```
{ userId: 1234, name: 'Mike' }
{ userId: 1235, name: 'John' }
...
```

I want to get a result of the form

```
dict[userId] = document
```

in other words, I want a result that is a dictionary where the `userId` is the key and the rest of the document is the value.

How can I do that?

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: Regardless, this looks like a rather simple programming task, was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: No specific language. Just the Mondo CLI (which is Javascript-like, in a way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$arrayToObject` to do that, you just need to format it to array of `k`, `v` before.

It is not clear if you want one dictionary for all documents, or each document in a dictionary format. I guess you want the first option, but I'm showing both:

**One dictionary** with all data*, requires a `$group` (which also format the data):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {$push: {k: {$toString: "$userId"},  v: "$$ROOT"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {data: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - one dict](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qMYMvOCO6xS)

*Notice that in this option, all the data is inserted to one document, and document as a limit size.

**Dictionary format**: If you want to get all documents as different results, but with a dictionary format, just replace the first step of the aggregation with this:

```
 {
    $project: {
      data: [{k: {$toString: "$userId"}, v: "$$ROOT"}],
      _id: 0
    }
  },
```

See how it works on the [playground example - dict per document](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rLaq7WqgPsC)