# Is it possible to group up all documents returned from a query into a dictionary-like structure based on one of their fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation, group

The title probably doesnt help much, but let me illustrate what im asking.

I have a mongodb database with a collection of statements and a collection of units.
Each statement document has a field called unitID which is the ID of the unit it belongs to, as a way to have a reference directly in the statement document.

What i am trying to do is find a way to query the statement collection, and instead of getting back for example 250 results documents, is it possible to use aggregation to somehow clump them up into a single document object that has the unitIDs as fields, and the relevant statement to that unitID as the value for each of those fields?

So for example, instead of a regular query that might look like this:

```
[{
  unitID:"unitID1"
  someData: "data",
  someOtherData: 123 
},{
  unitID:"unitID2",
  someData: "diffData",
  someOtherData:234
},
...]
```

it could look like this?

```
{
  unitID1:{...statement1Doc},
  unitID2:{...statement2Doc},

  ...
}
```

the main reason i want to do this is so i can handle very large responses as a dictionary, so instead of having an array and having to iterate through large arrays, i can just access a document directly with the unitID.

I am simplifying my use case, i know many answers might just be "do it differently" but the actual scenario is too complex to summarize in a simple question. So i just want to know if this is theoretically possible using $group or $bucket, which ive been trying to use but can't figure out how to get it to work right, as i dont think thats how it would group them.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Use `$arrayToObject`

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570374/how-to-turn-a-mongodb-query-into-a-dictionary/72571256#72571256